# Implicit Conversion from NSInteger to NSString not allowed in ARC.. what workaround should be used to deal with Integers

Tags: xcode, nsstring, ios5, xcode4.2, nsinteger

This is my code in my viewcontroller.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.abilitygeneration setText:((TestAbility *)[self.testabilities objectAtIndex:0]).abilitygeneration]; }
```

It gives me an error implicit conversion of NSInteger aka int to NSString is disallowed with ARC. How do I enable ARC and have a workaround for this.Instead of setText what can I use?

abilitygeneration is set as NSInteger in TestAbility.h file.. thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So if I've understood correctly, `setText:` takes an `NSString` and you have an `NSInteger`? If that's correct you can explicitly convert them as follows:

```
[self.abilitygeneration setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",((TestAbility *)[self.testabilities objectAtIndex:0]).abilitygeneration]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Precise and accurate